# CodeIgniter-3 PHP - How to access overriden child function through parent

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have two model classes in two seperate files.

```
class Parent_Model extends CI_Model {
    public function process() {
        return 'This is parent';
    }
}

class Child_Model extends Parent_Model {
    public function process() {
        return 'This is child';
    }
}
```

having below in `autoload.php`

```
$autoload['model'] = ['parent_model'];
```

In my controller i've added below code

```
$implementation_model = 'child_model'
$this->load->model($implementation_model);
$result = $this->parent_model->process();
```

`$implementation_model` is switchable at run-time.

Current code gives result as `This is parent`

How to get the child code to be executed?

Comment: How it can be overridden if you were not inheriting your `parent_class` within `child_class` over here. You were calling your `parent_model` class method `process` over here and not your `child_class` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing like this,

```
$implementation_model = 'child_model';// if no value is coming, just add below line.

$implementation_model = $implementation_model == "" ? "parent_model" : "child_model" ;
$this->load->model($implementation_model);
$result = $this->{$implementation_model}->process();
```

Explicitly you r calling `parent_model`. So change model with variable name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just after I posted this, i figured it out to use this way. Having heavy background on Java based app development, switching to this model is a steep learning curve.

Comment: Yes, this is working, but still i feel this is not a standard way, may be that's the way php is

Comment: For my knowledge, i think there is no problem in doing this. If answer was helpful, consider accepting it.